# Gson Strange NullPointerException while using websockets with java

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, websocket, gson

I am using websockets in java to connect to my nodeJS server.
I am also using Gson to parse request and response Json's.

I've got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

on this line:

```
    ConnectionResponse connectionResponse = gson.fromJson(messageContainer.getMessage(), ConnectionResponse.class);
```

if my Gson initialisation is not just before gson.toJson() method call.

This code works perfectly to me:

```
 import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        // open websocket
        final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI("ws://localhost:8000"));
        // add listener

        MessageContainer messageContainer = new MessageContainer();
        clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(messageContainer);

        // send message to websocket
        clientEndPoint.sendMessage("{\"type\":\"Connect\",\"name\":\"FrontClient\"}");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ConnectionResponse connectionResponse = gson.fromJson(messageContainer.getMessage(), ConnectionResponse.class);

        System.out.println(connectionResponse.toString() + "yay");


        // wait 5 seconds for messages from websocket
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

**But if i move 
            Gson gson = new Gson();
a somewhere before, it crashes with an error above.**

For example, this code doesn't work:

```
    import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // open websocket
        final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI("ws://localhost:8000"));
        // add listener

        MessageContainer messageContainer = new MessageContainer();
        clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(messageContainer);

        // send message to websocket
        clientEndPoint.sendMessage("{\"type\":\"Connect\",\"name\":\"FrontClient\"}");

        ConnectionResponse connectionResponse = gson.fromJson(messageContainer.getMessage(), ConnectionResponse.class);

        System.out.println(connectionResponse.toString() + "yay");


        // wait 5 seconds for messages from websocket
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

or this:

```
    import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            // open websocket
            final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI("ws://localhost:8000"));
            // add listener

        MessageContainer messageContainer = new MessageContainer();
        clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(messageContainer);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // send message to websocket
        clientEndPoint.sendMessage("{\"type\":\"Connect\",\"name\":\"FrontClient\"}");

        ConnectionResponse connectionResponse = gson.fromJson(messageContainer.getMessage(), ConnectionResponse.class);

        System.out.println(connectionResponse.toString() + "yay");


        // wait 5 seconds for messages from websocket
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Anyone could help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide a whole exception?  But a better way is to debug it with your IDE or add logging like System.out.println(); For all objects from line 23.

Comment: Another theory that "clientEndPoint.sendMessage" is asynchronous call and "new Gson()" constructor takes time which enough to receive server response. If you add "sleep(..)" before ".. gson.fromJson(messageContainer.getMessage(), ..)" it would work for any "new Gson()" position.

Comment: @MaksymProkhorenko your solution works, rly thanks :)

Comment: @MaksymProkhorenko  but isnt that really strange, that it works without Thread.sleep() when Gson initialisation is just before clientEndpoint.sendMessage() method? in this way, initialisation of Gson has the shortest time to initialize.. hmmm

Comment: I believe if you add network latency (like 200ms or more) into the picture, it would be enough to fail. I would suggest writing some checker which would wait for the response. Something like
while(messageContainer.getMessage() == null) { synchronized (clientEndPoint) {clientEndPoint.wait(5000L);}}
}
or https://dzone.com/articles/async-await-in-java